# Single Page BootStrap and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a web page that is single page, doesn't scroll; IE, takes up the whole width/height of the browser size the user has.

It will have buttons/navigation on the top or bottom.

So when the user click on the "contact" page, it will show up instead of the regular "home" intro page, likewise with the other pages without loading to a new url/page.

Does this make sense?
Similar to this.
https://itmeo.com/brut-premium-wordpress-theme/live/#!

I'm wondering if this is possible, if so, would JavaScript be beneficial in creating a site like this or would another language better fit this project?[image: Mock up of what I'm describing]

Comment: That is completely possible with CSS ... read about "overflow:hidden" and "position:fixed" for example ...

Comment: [How can I make DIV 100% height of browser without vertical scrolling of header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461067/how-can-i-make-div-100-height-of-browser-without-vertical-scrolling-of-header)

Comment: Possible duplicate of:-[How to make the web page height to fit screen height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868474/how-to-make-the-web-page-height-to-fit-screen-height)

Comment: You can Use the jQuery mobile framework for this. It would be so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should read more about **AJAX**.
SPA or "*single-page application*" have a havier usage of ajax. and also take time to read about *Developing cross-browser and cross-platform pages* to avoid inconsistency and issues on the design part.